# Parallel and Perpendicular lines?

Tags: geometry

I already know that his is probably answered somewhere, but please bear with me. So I gave `2x+y=5; (3,1)` I already know to bring it down to `y=2x+5` but don't know what to do next. If you guys have any links or anything, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Maybe you are given $2x+y=5$ and want the line perpendicular to this that passes through $(3,1)$. If so, rewrite as $y=-2x+6$. The slope of the line perpendicular to this is $\frac{1}{2}$. So the line has equation $y=\frac{1}{2}x+b$. Substitute $x=3$, $y=1$ to find $b$. Or maybe you want the line parallel to $y+2x+5$ that passes through $(3,1)$. The equation shas shape $y+2x=k$, find $k$.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference is a good place to find information about typing math here at MSE. You're not the only one who doesn't know what do to here...what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Xoque55 I need to write an equation in slope-intercept form. Also thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. But where did you get y=-2x+6? Wouldn't @AndréNicolas be y=-2x+5?

Comment: And what is the role of $(3,1)$? Anyway, if you subtract $2x$ from both sides, you would rather get $y=5-2x$.

Comment: I was told I needed to substitute them in. The 3 would be x and 1 is y. @Berci

Comment: The $6$ is a typo, my hand slipped. You need to clarify your question, then perhaps someone will write a detailed answer.

Comment: Alright. Thanks.@AndréNicolas

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the simplification you provided is incorrect. From the original equation

$2x+y=5$; Point 1: $(x_1, y_1)=(3, 1)$

...you would proceed by subtracting the $2x$ term from both sides. [Remember, algebraically, when you perform an operation on a mathematical equation, it must be applied equally and identically to both sides of that equation]. This requires that your resultant simplified equation -- an explicit formula for the dependent variable, $y$, in terms of the independent variable, $x$, be of the form:

$y=-2x+5$.

The formula for a line parallel to the equation of a line we are given (i.e., that above) requires it have the same slope. Therefore, any parallel line will have slope,

$m=-2$.

Next, simply plug-in the coordinates of the given point into their appropriate variable correspondents to find the equation of the parallel line sought. Use of the point-slope formula will most easily facilitate the generation of this equation.

$y=-2x+5$; Point 1: $(x_1, y_1)=(3, 1)$ [Known Information]

$\implies 
y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ [Point-Slope Formula]

$\implies y-(1)=-2(x-(3))$ [Input of Coordinates] $$\implies 
y-1=-2(x-3)

$\implies
y-1=-2x+6$ [having applied the Distributive Property]

$\implies
y=-2x+7$  [Final Equation; having added $+1$ to both sides]

Any line perpendicular to a line must have a slope given by the negative reciprocal of the slope of known line. Again, use of the point-slope formula will most easily help you determine the equation of the sought perpendicular line.

$y=-2x+3$; Point 1: $(x_1, y_1)=(3, 1)$ [Known Information]

$\implies$

Slope of Given Line, $m=-2$
Slope of Perpendicular Line $= (-1)\times(m^{-1})$
                            $$= (-1)\times((-2)^{-1})$$
                            $$= (-1)\times\left(-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$
                            $$= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ [Point-Slope Formula]

$\implies
y-(1)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(x-3)$ [Input Corresponding Values]

$\implies
y-1=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$ [Simplified Form After Distribution of $(1/2)$ Across Parentheses $(x-3)$]

$\implies
y=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ [Final Equation; having added $+1=\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)$ to both sides]

or

$y=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(x+1)$ [Final Equation In Factored Form]

Hope this helps. Let me know if I made any dumb errors.

Comment: I really, really thank you for such a spectacular answer. I did another problem and was wondering if I did it right.
`3x-y=5` and X=-1 and Y=-2. So I moved the y to the left and got y=3x+5, then y=3*-1+5*-2 and multiplied to get y=-3+-10. Is this correct?

Comment: Not sure if I need to tag you ^^

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You're very welcome.

Unfortunately, you did it incorrectly. The $y$ is already on the left so perhaps you meant you moved it to the right? Regardless, if you move the $y$ to the right (algebraically, this is equivalent to adding '$+y$' to the right and left hand sides of the equation. You would then have

$$3x-y+(y)=5+(y)$$.

On the left-hand side, the positive and negative $y$ terms cancel out. [Remember, this is what we want: for the terms on one side to cancel out so that we get a more simple answer when it is added to the other side where it (usually) does not cancel]. The result becomes

$3x=y+5$.

Since we are attempting to achieve an equation in slope-intercept form, we are not finished. [Slope-Intercept Form: $y=mx+b$, where $y$ is the independent variable, $m$ is the slope, $x$ is the independent variable (horizontal axis) and $b$ is the $y$-intercept]. Next, we subtract $5$ from both sides [an operation that is algebraically the same as adding negative five to both sides, or "$+(-5)$"]. We then have

$3x+(-5)=y+5+(-5)$.

Notice, as before, this is done and is useful to us because it leads to the cancellation of the constant '$5$' on the right-hand side giving us an explicit equation of $y$. [An explicit equation of one variable (here, the $y$-variable) means that you have an equation with only that variable on one side and all other terms on the other side]. The resultant equation is now in slope-intercept form and is given by

$3x-5=y$

...or, written in a form that's more convenient to us (at least, to me)

$y=3x-5$.

Now, using the given point we revert to point-slope form. [Point-Slope Form: $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$]. We know the slope from our calculation of the slope-intercept form. Namely, from "$y=3x-5$" we see that the slope is $m=3$ since three is the coefficient of $x$-variable. We are given the point. Point 1: $(x_1, y_1)=(-1, -2)$. Plug in the known values into point-slope form to arrive at the answer:

$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$; Point 1: $(x_1, y_1)=(-1, -2)$

[Point-Slope Form]
$y-(-2)=3(x-(-1))$

$\implies 
y+2=3(x+1)$ [Two negatives cancel to give a positive]

$\implies 
y+2=3x+3$ [Simplify by adding "$+(-2)$" to both sides]

$\implies 
y=3x+1$ [Final Answer]

---

Alternatively, you could have begun by adding "$+(-3x)$" to both sides:

$3x-y=5$ [Original Equation]

$\implies 
3x-y+(-3x)=5+(-3x)$ [having added "$+(-3x)$" to both sides] $$\implies
-y=5-3x$$

From here, you can see that you are left with a negative $y$ "$-y$" on the left-hand side. To achieve an equation in slope-intercept form, finish by multiplying both sides [just like with addition/subtraction, what you do to one side must be done to the other with multiplication/division].

$-y=5-3x$ [Simplified equation from above]
$(-y)\times (-1)=(5-3x)\times (-1)$ [having multiplied both sides by "$(-1)$"]

$\implies
y=3x-5$ [Slope-Intercept Form]

You can see that this method produces the exact same equation of a line in slope-intercept form as we found earlier. Complete the problem by reverting to point-slope form and using your given point just as I did earlier.